# Biblatex Customization and Problem with Babel

Tags: biblatex, babel

When I try to change the order of url and url date in biblatex via renewing url+urldate macro, errors arise. But it works fine when I disable babel.

Errors:

```
./mwe.tex:43: Use of \\blx@imc@bibstring doesn't match its definition. [\end]
./mwe.tex:43: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. [\end]
./mwe.tex:43: Argument of \@gobble has an extra }. [\end]
./mwe.tex:43: Paragraph ended before \@gobble was complete. [\end]
```

Here is mwe:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[a4paper, top=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=4cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, date=year, firstinits=true, natbib=true]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[turkish, shorthands=off]{babel}
    \usepackage{filecontents}


\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \printurldate}
  \printfield{url}}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @online{doe2014,
    author = {John Doe},
    title  = {Lorem Ipsum},
    date   = {2014},
    url    = {http://www.invalidurl.com},
    urldate = {2014-06-19}
}

\end{filecontents*}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\section{mwe}
{
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit \cite{doe2014}. Vivamus a fermentum tortor. Curabitur lacinia feugiat eros. Aenean sagittis pulvinar orci id sodales. Aenean vulputate leo elit, vitae euismod odio cursus sed. Integer nec risus semper, lobortis arcu nec, sodales urna. Sed convallis vitae justo nec vehicula. Maecenas eleifend, erat sit amet ultricies ultricies, mi nibh hendrerit arcu, in consequat leo dui vitae eros.  
}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

mwe.bbl

```
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 2.3 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber as required.
%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup


\refsection{0}
  \sortlist{entry}{nyt}
    \entry{doe2014}{online}{}
      \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=bd051a2f7a5f377e3a62581b0e0f8577}{Doe}{D\bibinitperiod}{John}{J\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=bd051a2f7a5f377e3a62581b0e0f8577}{Doe}{D\bibinitperiod}{John}{J\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{bd051a2f7a5f377e3a62581b0e0f8577}
      \strng{fullhash}{bd051a2f7a5f377e3a62581b0e0f8577}
      \field{sortinit}{D}
      \field{labelyear}{2014}
      \field{datelabelsource}{}
      \field{labeltitle}{Lorem Ipsum}
      \field{title}{Lorem Ipsum}
      \field{urlday}{19}
      \field{urlmonth}{06}
      \field{urlyear}{2014}
      \field{year}{2014}
      \verb{url}
      \verb http://www.invalidurl.com
      \endverb
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
\endrefsection
\endinput
```

Comment: It could be a babel bug. I did sent the maintainer a mail. It appears in your redefinition as the changed position triggers some "uppercase/lowercase" commands and so the bug is seen.

Comment: The macro must start with \printfield{url}} As long as it starts with printing url, I can customize the macro however I want. Otherwise it gives these errors. I actually tried removing the \printurldate altogether from the macro and adding it after this macro in @online driver. It raises the same errors.

Comment: I'll have a look at it, but I first need to reinstall biblatex and related tools (biber raises on my system an error related to a dll).

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to use biber for win. Please, ¿could you post a MWE not requiring generating any file? After reading the biblatex code I think both this package and babel are trying to patch \Make...case in incompatible ways, but I need to confirm it.

Comment: @JavierBezos Thank you bu what do you mean? I am very new to all this and I don't know how to make a MWE which doesn't require generating files.

Comment: @krypt After latexing this file you must process a file with biber, which creates another file. I mean the latter, the generated file.

Comment: @JavierBezos I am sorry I was very busy with a lot of stuff so I couldn't follow up. I've added the content of the file you asked for to the question.

Comment: @JavierBezos I don't think this is Win specific. I get what looks like the same error on GNU/Linux: `! Use of \\blx@imc@bibstring doesn't match its definition.
\@uclclist ...\languagename @bbl@uclc\endcsname }{
                                                  \bbl@tolower \@empty }{\bb...`.

Comment: @dfr Of course, as far as TeX is concerned. I was speaking of biber.

Comment: @krypt Thanks. Confirmed -- both babel and babelbib are patching \Make...case. Perhaps `babelbib` is more 'canonical', so I'll investigate how to modify babel for them to be compatible.

Comment: @JavierBezos Did you get anywhere with your investigations? I suppose so, since when I tried the MWE just now, it compiled perfectly fine. Can you confirm that the bug was fixed, so we can close this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to have been fixed. On an up-to-date machine the MWE above compiles fine without any errors (`biblatex` has no Turkish localisation, but that is a different matter).